# How to get thumbnail of a video uploaded to Google drive

Tags: android, web, google-drive-android-api

I am creating a web type application. I am able to show YouTube video thumbnail successfully from https://www.img.youtube.com/video_id ... But if there is any such way to show Google drive video thumbnail. Please help...

Answer (score 4):

Fetching thumbnails from videos uploaded on Google drive is as easy as fetching thumbnails from youtube videos.
Each drive video has a unique id just a youtube video.
Goto drive-->rightclick on video-->Get link
Eg. https://drive.google.com/file/d/<video_id>/view?usp=sharing

Put that video_id in the link format below and you'll be able to get the thumbnail without Google API

**https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=<video_id>**

Answer (score 1):

There is, you can use the Drive API's `get` function with field parameter `thumbnailLink`, it will return a URL to the video's thumbnail. Some things to keep in mind, the video needs to have been processed, which means, when you see it in the Drive folder, you should be able to see an actual thumbnail, not the video logo ([image: logo]).

You can find information on the [File Properties here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), and on the [get method of the Drive API here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). On that last one you can also test the method by writing `thumbnailLink` into the"fields" parameter.